# regex include text inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to alert the text inside brackets.  I can do this when I have square brackets.

```
    a = "1[the]"
    words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
    alert(words);
```

But I can't get it going with round brackets ()

I have tried a few different things but don't quite have my head around what I need to change here.

```
    a = "1(the)"
    words = a.match(/(^[\])+(?=])/g);
    alert(words);

    a = "1(the)"
    words = a.match(/[^(\)]+(?=])/g);
    alert(words);

    a = "1(the)"
    words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=))/g);
    alert(words);

    a = "1(the)"
    words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
    alert(words);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to escape the ()'s in your regexp. ()'s have special meaning, which is why it's not working.

Comment: You should probably try understand what your original regex is doing. `[^[\]]` matches anything *but* a `[` or `]` (see what character classes `[]` mean in regex as well as `^` inside a character class). So you just need to do the same, but round brackets instead of square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current regex doesn't technically look for words inside brackets. For example, if the string was `"foobar)"` it would match "foobar".

Try something like:

```
a = "1(the) foo(bar)"
regexp = /\((.*?)\)/g

// loop through matches
match = regexp.exec(a)
while (match != null) {
    alert(match[1]) # match[1] is captured group 1
    match = regexp.exec(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ()'s need to be escaped. They have special meaning, in that they are used to 'capture' specific groups of text matched by the pattern between them.

Edited to fix an issue with the way I interpreted the problem. Try again, this should work.

Try this:

```
a = "1(the)"
words = a.match(/[^\(\)]+(?=\))/g);
alert(words);
```

Comment: thanks I try this but get unterminated regular expression literal?

Comment: i want to alert the text inside the bracket so in my example I am expecting the

Comment: Yes, I've fixed the solution so it should capture text inside ()'s now.